# find who has all the exact values in the column in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, database

I have added the db script with data.

I need to fetch the records from table
"providers" whose values are available in "providersavl" table
by making sure that the values from both tables are not present in the third table "providerbreak" ( where SQL not in)

I need the following result using the query

```html
DECLARE @InString VARCHAR(50)= '10,11,12,13';
DECLARE @InTemp TABLE(KEYY TINYINT);
INSERT @InTemp(KEYY)
   SELECT VALUE FROM STRING_SPLIT(@InString,',')


SELECT X.PROVIDERID,X.VAL FROM
(
   SELECT P.PROVIDERID,P.val,
     COUNT(*)OVER (PARTITION BY P.PROVIDERID)XCOL
     FROM DBO.PROVIDERAVL AS P
     
     JOIN @InTemp T ON P.val=T.KEYY
     WHERE T.KEYY NOT IN 
     (SELECT VAL FROM PROVIDERBREAK) 
      
)X WHERE X.XCOL=(SELECT COUNT(*)FROM @InTemp)
```

```html
ProviderId   VAL
3            10
3            11
3            12
3            13
```

but its returning empty result.

Can anyone please help me??

```html
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[provideravl]    Script Date: 6/3/2022 10:41:46 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[provideravl](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [providerid] [int] NULL,
    [val] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_provideravl] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[providerbreak]    Script Date: 6/3/2022 10:41:46 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[providerbreak](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [providerid] [int] NULL,
    [val] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_providerbreak] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[providers]    Script Date: 6/3/2022 10:41:46 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[providers](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [val] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_providers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[provideravl] ON 
GO
INSERT [dbo].[provideravl] ([id], [providerid], [val]) VALUES (1, 1, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[provideravl] ([id], [providerid], [val]) VALUES (2, 1, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[provideravl] ([id], [providerid], [val]) VALUES (3, 1, 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[provideravl] ([id], [providerid], [val]) VALUES (4, 1, 4)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[provideravl] ([id], [providerid], [val]) VALUES (5, 1, 5)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[provideravl] ([id], [providerid], [val]) VALUES (6, 1, 6)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[provideravl] ([id], [providerid], [val]) VALUES (7, 1, 7)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[provideravl] ([id], [providerid], [val]) VALUES (8, 1, 8)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[provideravl] ([id], [providerid], [val]) VALUES (9, 1, 9)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[provideravl] ([id], [providerid], [val]) VALUES (10, 1, 10)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[provideravl] ([id], [providerid], [val]) VALUES (11, 2, 5)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[provideravl] ([id], [providerid], [val]) VALUES (12, 2, 6)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[provideravl] ([id], [providerid], [val]) VALUES (13, 2, 7)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[provideravl] ([id], [providerid], [val]) VALUES (14, 2, 8)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[provideravl] ([id], [providerid], [val]) VALUES (15, 2, 9)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[provideravl] ([id], [providerid], [val]) VALUES (16, 2, 10)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[provideravl] ([id], [providerid], [val]) VALUES (17, 2, 11)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[provideravl] ([id], [providerid], [val]) VALUES (18, 2, 12)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[provideravl] ([id], [providerid], [val]) VALUES (19, 2, 13)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[provideravl] ([id], [providerid], [val]) VALUES (20, 2, 14)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[provideravl] ([id], [providerid], [val]) VALUES (21, 2, 15)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[provideravl] ([id], [providerid], [val]) VALUES (22, 2, 16)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[provideravl] ([id], [providerid], [val]) VALUES (23, 2, 17)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[provideravl] ([id], [providerid], [val]) VALUES (24, 2, 18)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[provideravl] ([id], [providerid], [val]) VALUES (25, 2, 19)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[provideravl] ([id], [providerid], [val]) VALUES (26, 2, 20)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[provideravl] ([id], [providerid], [val]) VALUES (27, 3, 9)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[provideravl] ([id], [providerid], [val]) VALUES (28, 3, 10)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[provideravl] ([id], [providerid], [val]) VALUES (29, 3, 11)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[provideravl] ([id], [providerid], [val]) VALUES (30, 3, 12)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[provideravl] ([id], [providerid], [val]) VALUES (31, 3, 13)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[provideravl] ([id], [providerid], [val]) VALUES (32, 3, 14)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[provideravl] ([id], [providerid], [val]) VALUES (33, 3, 15)
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[provideravl] OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[providerbreak] ON 
GO
INSERT [dbo].[providerbreak] ([id], [providerid], [val]) VALUES (1, 2, 10)
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[providerbreak] OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[providers] ON 
GO
INSERT [dbo].[providers] ([id], [name], [val]) VALUES (1, N'Asif', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[providers] ([id], [name], [val]) VALUES (2, N'Sajid', 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[providers] ([id], [name], [val]) VALUES (21, N'Qasim', 3)
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[providers] OFF
GO
USE [master]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [TEST] SET  READ_WRITE 
GO
```

Comment: please provide some sample data and desired output

Comment: I am trying to add picture and code snippet but not getting it

Comment: Just added the table script with data.

Comment: What is your SQL Server version? `SELECT @@VERSION;`

Comment: Its Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)   - Developer Edition

Comment: @Sergey can you please help

Comment: @crystalogic when asked for clarification you should [edit] the question and put those details in the body of the question. Comments are not part of the Q&A.

Comment: @clvrmnky thank you for correction. BTW I believe I have all details in question section.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @InString VARCHAR(50)= '9,10,11,12,13';
DECLARE @InTemp TABLE(KEYY TINYINT);
INSERT @InTemp(KEYY)
   SELECT VALUE FROM STRING_SPLIT(@InString,',')


SELECT X.NAME,X.VAL FROM
(
   SELECT P.NAME,P.val,
     COUNT(*)OVER (PARTITION BY P.NAME)XCOL
     FROM DBO.PROVIDERS AS P
     JOIN @InTemp T ON P.val=T.KEYY
)X WHERE X.XCOL=(SELECT COUNT(*)FROM @InTemp)
```

I hope it can be somehow simplified

Comment: Dear @Sergey, I need another solution, can you please see my edited question?

Comment: I guess, it would be easier to everyone to help you if you create a new question. If I understand your amended requirement correctly, you can use something like this   SELECT P.[id],P.[name],P.[val]
FROM [dbo].[providers] AS P
WHERE EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[provideravl] AS A
  WHERE P.id=A.providerid
)
AND NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[providerbreak]AS B
  WHERE P.id=B.providerid
)

Comment: Actually its not allowing me to post another question thats why I edited :(

Comment: Also the new answer doesn't meet the requirement